# How to extract data from optional parameter in angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have object which contains user details(such as name , email etc..) i am passing this object as an optional parameter in url when i try to extract this obj in another component it showing [object object] even i tried JSON.Stringfy but cannot able to extract.

```
user has {"id":5,"name":"Chelsey Dietrich","username":"Kamren","email":"Lucio_Hettinger@annie.ca","address":{"street":"Skiles Walks","suite":"Suite 351","city":"Roscoeview","zipcode":"33263","geo":{"lat":"-31.8129","lng":"62.5342"}},"phone":"(254)954-1289","website":"demarco.info","company":{"name":"Keebler LLC","catchPhrase":"User-centric fault-tolerant solution","bs":"revolutionize end-to-end systems"}}
 passID(user){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
    this._router.navigate(['/detail', user.id, {user}]);
  }
```

Receiver part(detail component)

```
 this._ActiveRoute.params.subscribe((params:Params) => {
                let id = parseInt(params['id']);
                this.userID = id;//success

                let output = params['user'];
               console.log(output)// cant able to extract object([object object])

Browser URL - http://localhost:4200/detail/5;user=%5Bobject%20Object%5D
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your url

```
http://localhost:4200/detail/5;user=%5Bobject%20Object%5D
```

router.navigate() expects strings to be passed in for the parameters. you can see [object Object] is being passed into your url instead of the actual object. This is because (object).toString() produces [object Object]. Try stringifying the object before passing it in.

```
this._router.navigate(['/detail', user.id, {user: JSON.stringify(user)}]);
```

to use the stringified object you'll need to parse it in your subscription

```
// output equals the object you passed in
let output = JSON.parse(params['user']);
```

Comment: I just tried this and the above code *did* work for me. You do need the stringify here. (You had mentioned in your post that you had tried that ... but this *is* working for me.)

Comment: Is this possible to hide the object in URL?

Comment: @BalaganapathyNT not hide necessarily. You could encode it I suppose. An alternative (to have that variable persist through multiple sessions) is to store the user object inside localStorage.

Comment: @LLai - kindly suggest answer for this question.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45034602/how-to-show-md-error-message-for-dynamic-form-array/45034644#45034644